# How to return array element whose first index is the largest number in JS?

Tags: javascript

Given the array below, how I can return the element whose first index contains the highest number:

```
let ar = [[1,24], [2, 6]]
```

I've tried many proposed solutions, but they return the number itself, while it should be, in the case above `[2,6]`

One of the solutions I've tried is, but it returns `24, 6`:

```
var maxRow = arr.map(function(row){ return Math.max.apply(Math, row); });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do what you require you can use `reduce()` to compare the values of the first item in each child array and return the one with the highest value:

```js
let ar = [[1,24], [2, 6]]
let result = ar.reduce((acc, cur) => acc[0] < cur[0] ? cur : acc);  
console.log(result);
```

Comment: It would take me months to get there, being a self-taught. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help. Here's more info on [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

One way is using a reduce. Try like this:

```js
const ar = [
  [1,24],
  [2, 6],
];

const biggest = ar.reduce(
  (acc, cur) => cur[0] > (acc?.[0] || 0) ? cur : acc,
  [],
);

console.log(biggest);
```